# Why am I getting SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier?

Tags: node.js

*Sorry for asking such dumb question but I spent some time on this and looked to other similar questions and none of them were helpful*

I'm defining a function inside `var Tools = module.exports` and I have no clue of what is going wrong in this function definition:

```
getLastNRows: function (whereIsData, DB_info, table, NRows, callback) {
  if (whereIsData == "MySQL") {
    var queryString = "SELECT timestamp, temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, level_ice_bank, flow, power, level_change_rate FROM " +
                      table + " ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT " + NRows + ";";
    var connnection = mysql.createConnection(DB_info);
    connnection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Couldn't connect to the required MySQL DB.");
        console.log("DID NOT GET LAST " + NRows + " ROWS");
        throw err;
      }
    });
    connnection.query(queryString, function (err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("DID NOT GET LAST " + NRows + " ROWS");
        throw err;
      }
      Tools.setValue(rows);
      Tools.dataArray2Object(Tools.result_arr);
      callback();
    });
  }
  else {
    console.log("Function doesn't accept this DB service.\n(u still have to improve...)");
    return;
  }
 },
```

I'm getting:

```
      getLastNRows: function (whereIsData, DB_info, table, NRows, callback) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
 
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Maybe someone catches the error here?

Comment: Most probably you forgot to add a comma on the previous line.

Comment: True. Thanks for your time and sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that's an object, and you've just missed the comma before the first row you posted:

```
var myMethods = {
  foo: function () {}, // < This comma
  getLastNRows: function (whereIsData, DB_info, table, NRows, callback) {
      ...
  },
};
```

When you get syntax errors, it means something is wrong with the syntax (the program doesn't even execute).